# Looping over pandas data frame applying formula to each value

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
            PC1     PC2     PC3     PC4     PC5     PC6     PC7
ind                                                                       
NA06984 -0.0082 -0.0594 -0.0148 -0.0569 -0.1128 -0.0276 -0.0217 
NA06986 -0.0131 -0.0659 -0.0426  0.0654  0.0473  0.0603 -0.0454  
NA06989 -0.0073 -0.0551 -0.0457  0.0971 -0.0051 -0.0123  0.0035  
NA06994 -0.0051 -0.0599 -0.0239  0.0930  0.0765  0.0321  0.0392  
NA07000 -0.0046 -0.0362  0.0006 -0.0639 -0.0197 -0.0132  0.0631  
NA07037 -0.0132 -0.0600 -0.0252 -0.0381 -0.0091  0.0005  0.0235  
NA07048 -0.0128 -0.0653 -0.0234 -0.0417  0.0233  0.1034  0.0180  
NA07051 -0.0028 -0.0591 -0.0117 -0.0791 -0.0387  0.0102 -0.0840  
NA07056 -0.0121 -0.0389  0.0113 -0.0754  0.0226 -0.0304 -0.0490  
NA07347 -0.0192 -0.0441 -0.0588  0.1099 -0.0414  0.0505  0.0295
NA07357 -0.0100 -0.0360 -0.0268 -0.0621 -0.0737 -0.0090  0.0379
```

and I would like to standardize the distributions of each column, i.e. applying the formula

column_i[row_j] - column_i.mean()) / column_i.std()

for every value in every column, and substitute the original data frame with these values.

So far I have come up with

```
for index, row in evec_pandas.iterrows():
    new_row = None
    evec_pandas.loc[index,'PC1'] = (row['PC1'] - evec_pandas['PC1'].mean()) / evec_pandas['PC1'].std()

 print evec_pandas
```

but the results are

```
              PC1     PC2     PC3     PC4     PC5     PC6     PC7
ind                                                                         
NA06984  0.343471 -0.0594 -0.0148 -0.0569 -0.1128 -0.0276 -0.0217  
NA06986 -0.330077 -0.0659 -0.0426  0.0654  0.0473  0.0603 -0.0454 
NA06989 -0.003975 -0.0551 -0.0457  0.0971 -0.0051 -0.0123  0.0035  
NA06994  0.008607 -0.0599 -0.0239  0.0930  0.0765  0.0321  0.0392  
NA07000  0.003659 -0.0362  0.0006 -0.0639 -0.0197 -0.0132  0.0631  
NA07037 -0.058300 -0.0600 -0.0252 -0.0381 -0.0091  0.0005  0.0235 
NA07048 -0.028319 -0.0653 -0.0234 -0.0417  0.0233  0.1034  0.0180  
NA07051  0.046818 -0.0591 -0.0117 -0.0791 -0.0387  0.0102 -0.0840  
NA07056 -0.043817 -0.0389  0.0113 -0.0754  0.0226 -0.0304 -0.0490   
NA07347 -0.071195 -0.0441 -0.0588  0.1099 -0.0414  0.0505  0.0295 
NA07357  0.019495 -0.0360 -0.0268 -0.0621 -0.0737 -0.0090  0.0379
```

The first value is correct (0.343471), but the rest of the values in the PC1 column are not, and of course the rest of columns have no changes. If I use:

```
for index, row in evec_pandas.iterrows():
    new_row = None
    new_row = (row['PC1'] - evec_pandas['PC1'].mean()) / evec_pandas['PC1'].std()
    print new_row
```

I do obtain the PC1 column as it should be, but as an independent object, not inside the data frame:

```
0.343471311655
-0.673732188246
0.530304607555
0.987008219756
1.09080449526
-0.694491443346
-0.611454422946
1.46447108706
-0.466139637246
-1.94004674935
-0.0301952801455
```

So I need to substitute PC1 with these values, and then do the same for each column; I had thought of something like

```
for index, column in evec_pandas.iteritems():
    for index, row in evec_pandas.iterrows():
        new_row = None
        evec_pandas.loc[index,column] = (row[column] - evec_pandas[column].mean()) / evec_pandas[column].std()
```

But I understand it won't work like this. Any ideas?

The desired output would be:

```
                PC1        PC2          PC3        PC4        PC5        PC6         PC7
NA06984  0.34347131 -0.5760881  0.439607045 -0.6710009 -1.8594019 -1.0130591 -0.50633142
NA06986 -0.67373219 -1.1365003 -0.929352573  0.9013689  1.0906816  1.0794999 -1.02745500
NA06989  0.53030461 -0.2053539 -1.082006343  1.3089251  0.1251327 -0.6488253  0.04777466
NA06994  0.98700822 -0.6191967 -0.008505635  1.2562128  1.6287356  0.4081670  0.83275827
NA07000  1.09080450  1.4241525  1.197951582 -0.7609975 -0.1438943 -0.6702508  1.35827952
NA07037 -0.69449144 -0.6278185 -0.072521733 -0.4292956  0.0514267 -0.3441068  0.48754139
NA07048 -0.61145442 -1.0847700  0.016115941 -0.4755796  0.6484455  2.1055441  0.36660554
NA07051  1.46447109 -0.5502229  0.592260816 -0.9564188 -0.4939979 -0.1131873 -1.87620479
NA07056 -0.46613964  1.1913658  1.724853306 -0.9088491  0.6355469 -1.0797163 -1.10661301
NA07347 -1.94004675  0.7430361 -1.727091631  1.4734904 -0.5437494  0.8461998  0.61947141
NA07357 -0.03019528  1.4413959 -0.151310775 -0.7378555 -1.1389255 -0.5702651  0.80417343
```

Comment: you should be able to just do `(df - df.mean())/df.std()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do the following:

```
In [19]:
(df - df.mean())/df.std()

Out[19]:
              PC1       PC2       PC3       PC4       PC5       PC6       PC7
ind                                                                          
NA06984  0.343471 -0.576088  0.439607 -0.671001 -1.859402 -1.013059 -0.506331
NA06986 -0.673732 -1.136500 -0.929353  0.901369  1.090682  1.079500 -1.027455
NA06989  0.530305 -0.205354 -1.082006  1.308925  0.125133 -0.648825  0.047775
NA06994  0.987008 -0.619197 -0.008506  1.256213  1.628736  0.408167  0.832758
NA07000  1.090804  1.424152  1.197952 -0.760998 -0.143894 -0.670251  1.358280
NA07037 -0.694491 -0.627818 -0.072522 -0.429296  0.051427 -0.344107  0.487541
NA07048 -0.611454 -1.084770  0.016116 -0.475580  0.648445  2.105544  0.366606
NA07051  1.464471 -0.550223  0.592261 -0.956419 -0.493998 -0.113187 -1.876205
NA07056 -0.466140  1.191366  1.724853 -0.908849  0.635547 -1.079716 -1.106613
NA07347 -1.940047  0.743036 -1.727092  1.473490 -0.543749  0.846200  0.619471
NA07357 -0.030195  1.441396 -0.151311 -0.737856 -1.138926 -0.570265  0.804173
```

This will operate on the whole df so there is no need to iterate over rows/columns

Comment: So simple... the only problem is that the output is not in the proper column order, the given order is PC1, PC10, PC11... and then PC2, PC20 etc, any idea why this is happening? The code is:  new_file = (df - df.mean())/df.std()
print new_file

Comment: I don't know because you didn't post that data but you can reorder the column order, try `new_file.sort_index(axis=1)`

Comment: Yes, I posted only until column 7 but actually it has 21 columns, and after applying the formula the column order is PC1 PC10 PC11...PC2 PC20 PC21 PC3 PC4 ...PC9. And using the sort_index function it remains also like this...

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce this, you can re-specify the order by reindexing but in general the column should not change. so `new_file = new_file.ix[:, your_col_list]` will reindex the column order to whatever your list is

Comment: Thanks, I created     list = list(df.columns)    and then I added it to new_file as you suggested.